# Do I have to provide an ascii-art to the ascii-art challenge?

Tags: discussion

The question is rather simple. I want to create [popularity-contests](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contests) and [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) question. I know what image should be, but it's not ascii-art - there are some ascii-art versions of image in internet though.

Because this is popularity contest, should I provide a image of final result, or should I leave it up to the audience to discard ugly pictures(or allow them, if the code is neat)?

Comment: I think a few more details might help us form a better opinion. I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't really want to give away the details, but I want to create a challenge - you have to print some image, but it has to be an ascii-art. For example, let's say that I want user to generate glass bottle image in ascii-art. Should I provide an exact image I want to be generated, or just general guidelines(since there are other restrictions too), and since it's popularity-contest, hope that audience will know best? This will result in different images for bottle, and I'm asking if that's an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than asking for opinions without giving us enough details to be able to give a sensible answer*, use the resource that we already have for getting feedback on whether a question is well designed and worded or not: [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/194).

** Because what sensible person is going to say "Yes, that's fine" and risk you posting something which they don't think is fine and then pointing to their earlier answer?*

Comment: Well, actually I used sandbox now.